# Increasing the index of every elements in array when adding a new element

Tags: java, queue

hi guys I'm trying to increase the index of every elements in my array when i try to insert a new element everytime.

```
public void enqueue(Object inValue)
{
    if(isFull())
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Full.");
    }
    else
    {
        queue[count] = inValue;
        count += 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // creating queue
    Queue q = new Queue();

    // adding items into queue
    q.enqueue("1");
    q.enqueue("2");
    q.enqueue("3");
}
```

this will lead to q[0] = 1, q[1] = 2 and q[2] = 3. but what i actually want is: after i added q.enqueue("2") the array become : q[0] = 2 , q[1] = 1 and after q.enqueue("3") the array should look like this : q[0] = 3 , q[1] = 2, q[0] = 1.

Im truly sorry for the bad expression. Hope you guys are able to understand my problem. 
I'd been trying this for few hours but still couldn't figure out a single clue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use arraycopy https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int), creating empty array and putting new item on [0] than copy the rest.

Although. First you should think if you really need to do that. What is your problem?

Comment: My problem is doing infix to postfix using stack and queue class but not importing Java.util.stack and queue. I have to create stack and queue class by myself. I'd already done stack but stucked at queue which was the question I posted . P.s stack class cache operators with last in first out and queue class cache operands with first in first out

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a linked list internally, instead of an array. Then you don't have to shift every element over when you add a new element. And you don't have to worry about it ever getting full (other than, due to memory exhaustion).

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Queue<E> {

    private LinkedList<E> list;
    ...

    public void enqueue(E e) {
        list.addFirst(e); // adds element to the front.
    }
}
```